# If G is a group of order pq(p> q primes), why isn't it cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

The Sylow Theorem tells me that there is a subgroup $P$ of order $p$, which is normal in $G$. Also tells me that there is another subgroup $Q$ of order $q$. Also, $P \cap Q=1$ and $|P||Q|=|G|$. This would imply $G \simeq P\times Q \simeq Z/pZ\times Z/qZ \simeq Z/pqZ$ (by the Chinese remainder theorem), which is cyclic... What is wrong with my argument?

Edit: Here I'm using a theorem that states that if $T$ is a group, $D$, $E$ are subgroups of T with $D\cap E=\{e\}$ and if at least one of $D$ or $E$ is normal in G, then $DE\simeq D\times E$. If also $|D||E|=|G|$, then $G \simeq D\times E$.

Comment: How did you get that $P$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: You need both of $P$ and $Q$ to be normal in order to know $G = P \times Q$. Think dihedral groups of order $2p$.

Comment: You should probably be clear about what you are asking. $Z_{pq}$ is a group of order $pq$ that is cyclic, so it makes no sense to ask why it isn't cyclic. I presume you're asking how does, e.g. $S_3$ get around that argument? Well, in $S_3$ there is indeed an subgroup of order 3 and 2 and they have trivial intersection. However the subgroup with order 2 is not normal.

Comment: I think $P$ is indeed normal in $G$, since the index of $P$ in $G$ is $q$, which is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$. However, you can't conclude that $G$ is the direct product of $P$ and $Q$, since there may be a nontrivial map from $Q$ into $Aut(P)$; all you can say is that $G$ is a semidirect product of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: That theorem is incorrect as stated, as the example of the dihedral group shows. The correct formulation is in terms of semidirect products.

Comment: In response to your edit, that theorem must be wrong since it fails on the $S_3$ example (since the order 3 subgroup is normal). I would note also that your proof goes through provided q does not divide p-1, in which case you are assured both subgroups are normal

Comment: @AlexWertheim, yes you are right, I was trying to say $Q$ instead of $P$, didn't see the $p>q$ condition.

Comment: The condition of being cyclic is somewhat different: if $G$ is of order $n$ and $n$ is coprime to $\phi(n)$ then $G$ is necessarily cyclic. If $n$ is not coprime to $n$ then there exist cyclic as well as non-cyclic groups of order $n$. For $n = pq$ we have $\phi(n) = (p - 1)(q - 1)$ and then $\phi(n)$ is coprime to $n$ unless only one of $p, q$ is even. In other words if $n = pq$ and both $p, q$ are odd primes then a group of order $n$ is necessarily cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not always the case that $H$ being normal in $G$ means that $G=H\times K$ for some subgroup $K$. Check the source of the lemma you discuss in the edit. That is true if *both* groups are normal, but not always true if one group is and the other isn't. Alternatively, maybe the theorem uses semidirect products instead of direct products. That would also make the lemma true.  $D_6$ is a counterexample, as $C_3$ is normal in it. Your theorem tells us that $D_8=C_3\times C_2$ but that's not true.

Answer (score 0):

$G \simeq P\times Q $ implies that $P$ and $Q$ commute elementwise, but this needs not be the case.

The commutativity obstruction is the only one here because if $G$ is abelian of order $pq$ with $p\ne q$, then $G$ is cyclic.